How can I use custom names — or aliases — for sessions with GNU screen?
I want to be able to screen -r using a custom title I set to a running session.
For example, I want to be able to do something like screen -t customname, then later do screen -r customname.
However, screen -r only accepts [pid.]tty.host. How do I use custom names?

Start a screen with screen -S customname. Then re-connect to it with screen -r customname. Note that when you do screen -ls you'll see that the complete name will be [process id].customname, but you can still just use customname itself.
I like to create a couple such screens at bootup (using crontab's @reboot directive), automatically running a script, detached and waiting to be connected, like this:
screen -S customname -d -m script.sh


You can also rename an existing session with the sessionname <newname> command, after pressing C-a :. The manual warns however that the $STY environment variables will still reflect the old name  in  pre-existing  shells.
